# How to integrate ReSharper with WebStorm

Tags: angular, resharper, webstorm, resharper-8.0

Is it possible to integrate ReSharper with WebStorm for Angular application development? If yes can you please provide the steps or links which I can refer.

I tried checking in ReSharper official website but didn't get much info or I can say its bit confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - Resharper is an extension for Visual Studio only. I have not used WebStorm but I am sure it has many Resharper features built in as it is a Jetbrains product.